# Why the confluence plugin does not load

Tags: java, spring, maven, plugins, confluence

I tried some solutions her on stackoverflow already, and it did not solve my problem, so I wanted to include the question myself. I have been collaborating with a team, so the initial program was written by me. When I run 'atlas-run' the terminal shows the following messages:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-07-12 10:33:45,748 ERROR [main] [ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/confluence]] log Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.atlassian.confluence.setup.ConfluenceConfigurationListener]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.<clinit>(Collator.java:946)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.value.CompareMode.<clinit>(CompareMode.java:58)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:83)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.server.TcpServer.initManagementDb(TcpServer.java:94)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.server.TcpServer.start(TcpServer.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.h2.tools.Server.start(Server.java:476)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.h2.ServerLifecycle.start(ServerLifecycle.java:83)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.core.persistence.hibernate.ConfluenceHibernateConfig.getHibernateProperties(ConfluenceHibernateConfig.java:51)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.DefaultBootstrapManager.getHibernateProperties(DefaultBootstrapManager.java:646)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.DefaultBootstrapManager.performPersistenceUpgrade(DefaultBootstrapManager.java:332)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.init(DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.DefaultBootstrapManager.init(DefaultBootstrapManager.java:179)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.config.util.BootstrapUtils.init(BootstrapUtils.java:36)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.ConfluenceConfigurationListener.initialiseBootstrapContext(ConfluenceConfigurationListener.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.ConfluenceConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(ConfluenceConfigurationListener.java:64)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 12, 2021 10:33:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 12, 2021 10:33:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Context [/confluence] startup failed due to previous errors
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 60 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-07-12 10:33:45,763 INFO [main] [atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener] contextInitialized Initialising plugin system
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-07-12 10:33:45,763 FATAL [main] [atlassian.spring.container.SpringContainerContext] getComponent Spring Application context has not been set
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-07-12 10:33:45,763 ERROR [main] [atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener] contextInitialized Error initialising plugin manager: Spring Application context has not been set
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Application context has not been set
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.spring.container.SpringContainerContext.getComponent(SpringContainerContext.java:48)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.spring.container.ContainerManager.getComponent(ContainerManager.java:33)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener.getPluginSystemLifecycle(PluginFrameworkContextListener.java:190)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginFrameworkContextListener.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2021-07-12 10:33:45,769 FATAL [main] [atlassian.spring.container.SpringContainerContext] getComponent Spring Application context has not been set
```

And the plugin does not load, so I cant test it.

Comment: Could be this bug https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-60095, which version of Confluence, and which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I dont think so, that bug has this final statement: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
        at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:191)
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
        at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69) " while mine does not.    My versions are: Confluence 6.9.1, and java 1.8.0_291. And I should mention that already tried to update to version 7.x, 7.12.3 to be precise, and AMPS 8.2.2, with no success.

Comment: Look at the stack trace you have posted. That is the error, and it is expected with that JDK and Confluence 6.9.1. Please upgrade your Confluence version, and post the error message you get with 7.12.3. Perhaps it's a different problem.

Comment: Confluence 6.9.1 is EOL, by the way.